# Function causing error in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am learning javascript online, I am stuck at a point where I need to call a function

```
var creditCheck = function (income)
{
    if (income>=100)
    {
       return console.log("You earn a lot of money! You qulaify for a credit card.");
    }
    else {
       return console.log("Alas yo do not qualify for credit card. Capitalism is creul like that.");
    }
};

creditCheck(75);
```

The above is my code in which I am calling the `creditCheck` function. Now when I put 75 in function parameter `else` command (i.e `"Alas yo do not qualify for credit card. Capitalism is creul like that."`) is executing twice in a console.

Why is this text appearing two times in console ?

Thanks

Comment: only appears once here.

Comment: Works perfectly fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/2JT37/

Comment: Why are you returning a `console.log`??

Comment: I'm only getting one console.log

Comment: Thanks every one for you comments, I am testing this on the online tutorial site where I am getting the problem.

@Stephen Thomas: Even after removing the return I am still getting this twice in console

You ppl can check this code here:
[link](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/javascript-beginner-en-6LzGd/2/4?curriculum_id=506324b3a7dffd00020bf661#)

May be it's a glitch in that site

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: CodeAcademy automatically will call the function with an argument of 75, so there is no need for you to call that function. For your code, you want to return a string, so instead of returning a `console.log`, return the string inside the console.log, like

```
return "You earn a lot of money! You qulaify for a credit card."; //or whatever the string is
```

This code will pass the test:

```
var creditCheck = function (income)
{
    if (income>=100)
    {
       return "You earn a lot of money! You qualify for a credit card."
    }
    else {
       return  'Alas you do not qualify for a credit card. Capitalism is cruel like that.' ;
    }
};
```

When I run it in my console, I'm only getting one statement. I'm guessing that you're calling it elsewhere. Post your entire code, or it would be very hard to help you. However, when you say `return console.log()`, you're returning `undefined` every single time, so it's doing nothing useful. What you might want to do instead is

```
var creditCheck = function (income)
{
    if (income>=100)
    {
       console.log("You earn a lot of money! You qulaify for a credit card.");
       return true; //or return "You earn a lot of money!"
    }
    else {
       console.log("Alas yo do not qualify for credit card. Capitalism is creul like that.");
       return false;//or  return "You don't qualify";
    }
};

creditCheck(75);
```

Comment: @scrblndr3: Thanks 

This is entire code :D
I am currently testing this part only

Comment: @user2828488 That will work now, you're returning a console.log(), which will evaluate to return undefined every time, instead of returning a stirng

Comment: @ scrblnrd3: Thanks for ur answer but still the website is giving me error so it means that this is the problem with the site .

Any suggestions that whch software should I use to check my code offline not on site ?

Thanks :)

Comment: The website isn't giving you an error, you have typos in your strings

Comment: I have copied ur code and replaced the string with the string on site but it is still giving me error

Comment: whoops, forgot to take out the `return true`